# overusage of RAM in Hypervm VPS

Tags: vps, memory

I have a VPS running on hypervm

in proceses list i have something like this

```
> /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
> --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/

user : mysql
```

which takes 150 mb RAM

and then

```
    /usr/sbin/named -u named -t /var/named/chroot 

user : Named
```

50 mb RAM taken by this process

how can i solve this overusage of RAM and reduce it .

I have access to root and SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use MySQL and/or Bind on this VPS? If not, remove or disable them. Otherwise, you'll need to dive into the configuration files for both services.

If all else fails, add more memory!

Comment: that's correct bind and mysql are not good togather..

Answer (score 4):

HyperVM isn't a virtualization platform, it's a control panel for either OpenVZ or Xen. Which of those your VPS is running on could be important for solving this, so you should find out which you are using.

If you're on OpenVZ, some of that memory "usage" could come from it measuring stack allocation instead of actual used memory. You should run 'ps aux' and pay attention to the RSS and the VSZ fields. If named or mysql are low in RSS but high in VSZ, you should try reducing the stack size with something like 'ulimit -s 256' in the startup script for the service. [See lowendbox's article on this](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/reduce-stack-limit-for-multi-thread-apps/).

MySQL's memory usage can be cut way down by removing non-MyISAM table support, if your application will be alright with that. lowendbox has many articles about this, including [one on running 18 static sites *and* wordpress on a *64MB* VPS](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/yes-you-can-run-18-static-sites-on-a-64mb-link-1-vps/).